# Unknown Payload in transform message Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have a problem with transform message. I need to recieve messages in SOAP/WSDL sistem. In my case i have this structure for process the responses.

[image: Flow]

This is my flow and in trnasform message component i have this problem:

Y put credentials in transform message but if i see the web service component, say that payload is unknown.

[image: Content of transform message]

[image: Content of payloadweb service]

The problem is the sem for two transform message. I don't know how can i do to put the credentials good for doing a reception message aplication with SOAP/WSDL sistem.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to log the payload as `[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]`

If you can see the actual payload in XML or JSON format whatever you are POSTing, then extract the specific elements.

If your GET then in query params retrieve them using `[message.inboundProperties.'httpqueryparams']`

Extract the specfic elements into flowvars and set them to Webservice consumer add `[flowVars.userid]` and `[flowVars.pwd]`

That will echo back as response.

I hope this is going to help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, i try and response you if it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess here because you haven't shown exactly what your WSDL is expecting:

I think you may want a transform a bit like this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
---
{
    gdspHeader @(xmlns: "http://ws.gdsp.vf.gdspcustomer.com/" ) :{
        gsdpCredentials: {
            password: "Mule",
            userId: "Monty"

        }
    }

}
```

Which transforms to

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gdspHeader xmlns="http://ws.gdsp.vf.gdspcustomer.com/">
  <gsdpCredentials>
    <password>Mule</password>
    <userId>Monty</userId>
  </gsdpCredentials>
</gdspHeader>
```